# The best NoSQL solution for logging

Tags: java, logging, nosql

I am working on a project that is logging a lot of information about viewers from an online streaming platform. The problem today with the MySQL solution is that is too slow to query, and such.
Even with scaling and better performance tuning, that will now work because there are just to much data real time thats write/reads.

What will be a good(the best) NoSQL solution for me?

Extra:

- We are currently also using Amazon Web services, where we store our data.
- With Java API, and a open source solution is preferred.
- Object orientated.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a NoSQL solution , but have you looked at [Scribe](https://github.com/facebook/scribe) (from Facebook)? You can use http://code.google.com/p/scribe-log4j/ to write from Java

Answer (score 1):

I would spend some time looking at these options:

- [Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/LoggingToCassandra)
- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases)
- Hadoop

All of these solutions have their pros and cons, but their wikis should provide enough information to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The first challenge you may have is how to collect huge amount of data reliably with ease of management. There're some open-source log collector implementation such as syslog, [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/), [Scribe](http://github.com/facebook/scribe/), and [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/) :)

The big problem is how to store and process data. As you pointed out, using NoSQL solution works really well, but you need to choose among them depending on your data volume.

At first, you can use [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/) to store all of your data, but at some moment you end up using [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) to architect a massively scalable architecture.

The poing here is you should have a distributed logging layer which abstracts away the storage backend, and choosing the right NoSQL solution for data volume.

Here're some links to put the Apache Logs into MongoDB, or Hadoop HDFS by Fluentd.

- [Store Apache Logs into MongoDB](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/apache-to-mongodb)
- [Fluentd + HDFS: Instant Big Data Collection](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/http-to-hdfs)